# how to block my site from one known IP address?

Tags: networking, dns, security

I want to block access of my site from one particular IP address, how can i do that.?

using htaccess or ?

Comment: You need to specify if you want to do this in the code (and what language) or via the server.  Preferably via the server, and if so, this needs moved to server fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, in .htaccess, put the following

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 10.my.ip.address
```

Not 100% sure, so please let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP, put this in your configuration file. Replace strings and variables as necessary to change the IP address or level of hatred.

```
<?php
$ip = 255.255.255.255;
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $IP)
{
    die("I Hate You");
}
?>
```

I prefer this one:

```
    $ip = 255.255.255.255;
    if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $IP)
    {
        $array = array("I", "Hate", "You", "Alot");
        $message = $array[rand(0,3)];
        die($message);
    }
```

If they refresh the page enough, they might find out what I'm saying.